# Teams popover/indicator/thing causing issues with up/down vote arrows

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, tooltips

When viewing a question in Incognito mode I noticed the popover/indicator/thing had a design issue:

[image]

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know! We've moved some z-index constants around, and this one got lost in the shuffle. It'll go live in our next build.

Comment: [Some are suggesting the fix didn't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385965/560648)

Comment: Got it, technically these are separate bugs.

Comment: Another separate bug that looks the same [cropped up today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386270/7795130).