# Tooltip regarding private team should fill on top of upvote downvote in Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

The tooltip that comes up when you hover over Private team in stackoverflow for teams needs to come on top of the voting buttons, as shown:

[image]

Or anything for that matter:

[image]

Comment: It was reported as fixed yesterday: [Teams popover/indicator/thing causing issues with up/down vote arrows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385921/7795130), so either their new build hasn't gone out yet (more likely), or the fix wasn't quite right (less likely). I'm cautious to mark this as a dupe though in case it's the second one.

Comment: @DavyM The build number in the footer indicates the date of the last deploy. It was today (unless UTC time is throwing me off), so it seems like the latter.

Comment: Or caching since it sounds like an issue with css z-indices....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Caching shouldn't be a factor unless you have a severely misconfigured upstream proxy -- the JS and CSS URLs have a cache-busting hash URL suffix that is updated whenever the files change.

Comment: Usually caching is taken care of due to css / js packages that are already out there that make the url unique.

Comment: I put a comment on the other post and a dev said they're separate bugs. Though the outcome appears to be exactly the same so that makes me question the _testing_ (as always)

Answer (score 3):

This should now be resolved. Please let us know if you're still experiencing the issue.