# Weird UI bug with "What's This?" Popup for Q&A for work

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

I was scrolling through SO when I noticed the "Q&A for work" in the left column.

[image]

I clicked the "What's this?" link and got this:

[image]

This seems very ugly and if I were to guess with my limited knowledge of CSS, I would say someone messed up their z-indexes.

**EDIT:**

I looked around the site a bit more and found another example of this bug, but with tags:

[image]

Comment: Probably not a duplicate but at least related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385965/tooltip-regarding-private-team-should-fill-on-top-of-upvote-downvote-in-teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed. We’ve had a back and forth on our z-index strategy in CSS, and it should now be fixed... until the next z-index issue pops up, heheh. Thanks for reporting!